# Save response to variable

Tags: php, curl

I want to get response from callback out of that function but i got null value.

```
$rollingCurl = new \RollingCurl\RollingCurl();
$rollingCurl->post('https://example.com', $post);
print_r($outter);

$outter = array();

$rollingCurl
->setCallback(
    function (\RollingCurl\Request $request, \RollingCurl\RollingCurl $rollingCurl) use (&$outter) {
        if (preg_match_all('Error_(.*)', $request->getResponseText(), $out)) {
            $outter[$x++] = $out[0];
        }
        $rollingCurl->clearCompleted();
        $rollingCurl->prunePendingRequestQueue();

    }
```

Comment: Your callback doesn't return a value!

Comment: Are you sure that $outter[$x++] = $out[0]; executes ? try to make var_dump inside that if with preg_match, to see if it runs first.

Comment: It doesn't have value too, can someone explain me how to get that?